How to use graphQL in angular without using apollo client
I want to use graphQl in my angular app without using apollo client. Any idea how to do it?
I used apollo client for connecting graphQL API but I want to know how to use graphQL without apollo and any other client. Is it fine to use HttpClient or fetch without using apollo.

Yes. We can use GraphQL with Agnular without using Apollo Client. We can use fetch or axios and can make things work the same.
Below example demonstrates the usage of fetch to query a GraphQL endpoint.
fetch(<graphql_endpoint>, {
    method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: '{ posts { title } }' }),
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))

Same thing can be easily achieved using axios. Hope this helps!
